# On transitive actions on the sphere

Tags: lie-groups

A theorem of Borel asserts that $\mathbf{Sp}(n)\mathbf{Sp}(1)$ and $\mathbf{Sp}(n)\mathbf{U}(1)$ act  transitively in the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{4n-1}$. How can we describe these actions? Is there some resource where I can learn more about these groups and their actions in $\mathbb{S}^{4n-1}\subset \mathbb{H}^n$?

Comment: Where do you find this Theorem of Borel?

Comment: Are you aware that $\mathbf{Sp}(n)=\mathbf{U}(n,\mathbb{H})$?

Comment: Quaternionic linear transformations (i.e. real linear transformations of quaterion entry vectors, commuting with quaternionic scalar multiplication) clearly act transitively on the sphere, and $Sp(n)$ sits inside them and already acts transitively on the sphere. See Morton Curtis, Matrix Groups, for more detail on these actions.

Comment: Actually, Borel's Theorem list all compact Lie groups which act effectively and transitively in a sphere of a given dimension.
People usually quote this article:
 "Le plan projectif des octaves et les sphères comme espaces homogènes", C. R. Acac. Sc. Paris 230 (1950), A. Borel. 
But I can't get this article.

Comment: Basically, I know how the other Lie groups in the list are defined and how they act in the sphere and I wanted to know where I can find some information about  $\mathbf{Sp}(n)\mathbf{Sp}(1)$ and $\mathbf{Sp}(n)\mathbf{U}(1)$. I would need at least their definition and how they act in $\mathbb{S}^{4n-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions are in Morton Curtis, Matrix Groups, p. 27. The group $Sp(n)$ is the group of quaternionic linear transformations of a quaternionic vector space, which preserve a quaternionic bilinear positive definite form (all made precise by Curtis). The group $Sp(n)Sp(1)$ is the group of real linear transformations of a quaternionic vector space induced by those of $Sp(n)$ and by the group $Sp(1)$ of unit quaternion scalars. The subgroup $Sp(n)U(1)$ uses only the unit complex scalars. These all act by linear transformations, by definition, and preserve the real part of the quaternionic bilinear form, i.e. the real inner product. (Again, Curtis has all of the details.) Therefore they preserve the unit sphere in the quaternionic vector space. Moreover, already $Sp(n)$ acts transitively, which is easy to see by looking at the subgroup stabilizing a particular vector $e_1$, and then induction.

Comment: $\mathbf{Sp}(n)\mathbf{Sp}(1)$ is defined as the quotient of  the product $\mathbf{Sp}(n)\times\mathbf{Sp}(1)$ identifying $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. You can describe its action on $\mathbb{H}^n$ as $(A,\lambda) \in \mathbf{Sp}(n)\mathbf{Sp}(1)$ acts on $v\in \mathbb{H}^n$ like $Av\lambda^{-1}$. Also, a simple way to understand this action is considering three complex structures $\{J_i\}_{i=1}^3$ satisfying $J_i J_{i+1}=J_{i+2}$, for $i=1,2,3$. Then, there exists a unique $T\in  \mathbf{Sp}(n)\mathbf{Sp}(1)$ which sends a $\mathbb{H}$-orthonormal basis into another and satisfies $TJ_i=J_i T$.

Comment: But then how $\mathbf{Sp}(n)\mathbf{U}(1)$ acts on $\mathbb{H}^n$? Is there a similar easy description of its action in terms of $\mathbb{H}-orthogonal basis as the one I showed? Also, I couldn't find these details in Curtis' book.

Comment: The group $U(1)$ is a subgroup of $Sp(1)$: it is the group of unit complex numbers inside the group of unit quaternions. The action of $Sp(n)Sp(1)$ restricts to that of $Sp(n)U(1)$.

Comment: Ok, then I guess that there exists a unique $T\in \mathbf{Sp}(n)\mathbf{U}(1)$ which sends an $\mathbb{H}$-orthonormal basis into another and satisfies $TJ=JT$ for some fixed complex structure $J$. Is that correct?

Comment: No. There is a unique $T\in Sp(n)$ taking each $\mathbb{H}$-orthonormal basis into another. If you ask to have $e_j \mapsto Ae_j\lambda^{-1}$ be the identity, you clearly get $A=\lambda I$, and so there is a $T \in Sp(n)U(1)$ taking each $\mathbb{H}$-orthonormal basis into another, unique up to $Tv=\lambda v \lambda^{-1}$ for $\lambda \in U(1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!